# Python MPI Broadcast row in place

Tags: python, numpy, parallel-processing, mpi, mpi4py

So I'm trying to broadcast a row of an numpy array to every node, and have every node update that specific row in their own matrix.

So the code is as follows:

```
comm.Bcast([A[i, i:], A[i, i:].size, MPI.DOUBLE], root = root)
```

Where A is of type `numpy.array` and where `i` is an iteration variable.
When I try doing this, I ended with `A` becoming `None`.

What would the correct way be to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

This requires some numpy trickery. You need to take the `.data` of the buffer, and turn it into a new numpy buffer with offset and all that. This should be close to what you want:

```
datatype = np.intc
elementsize = datatype().itemsize
## or np.dtype('intc').itemsize
typechar = datatype().dtype.char
if procid==0:
    print("int size:",elementsize)
    print(typechar)

buffer = np.zeros( [nprocs,nprocs], dtype=datatype)
buffer[:,:] = -1
for proc in range(nprocs):
    if procid==proc:
        buffer[proc,:] = proc
    comm.Bcast\
        ( [ np.frombuffer\
            ( buffer.data,
              dtype=datatype,
              offset=(proc*nprocs+proc)*elementsize ),
            nprocs-proc, typechar ],
          root=proc )
    if procid==nprocs-1:
        print(buffer)

int size: 4
i
[[ 0  0  0  0]
 [-1 -1 -1 -1]
 [-1 -1 -1 -1]
 [-1 -1 -1 -1]]
[[ 0  0  0  0]
 [-1  1  1  1]
 [-1 -1 -1 -1]
 [-1 -1 -1 -1]]
[[ 0  0  0  0]
 [-1  1  1  1]
 [-1 -1  2  2]
 [-1 -1 -1 -1]]
[[ 0  0  0  0]
 [-1  1  1  1]
 [-1 -1  2  2]
 [ 3  3  3  3]]
```

Note that this requires that the elements you pick are contiguous. For sending a column you'd need derived types.